# Convert String to String[] but not with comma in apostrophes

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
String strValue = "city, image, N'Hello, World , It Rain', picture";
```

I want to convert to String[] and i used strValue.Split(',')

Result:

```
[
city, 
image, 
N'Hello, 
World, 
It Rain', 
picture
]
```

But I don't want to Split N'Hello, World , It Rain'

I want the result is:

```
[
city,
image,
N'Hello, World , It's Rain',
picture
]
```

Thank everyone.

Comment: Why you have this sql string at all? Use parameterized queries, don't concatenate strings

Comment: @Luke The fact that `N'a,b,c,d'` is returned as separate entries in the array rather than one word...

Comment: I had edited, please check again

Comment: are you ever going to have `'` appear in other fields or will it only appear in the context of `N'foo'`?

Comment: Write your own parser

Comment: What I can think of is using split for `'` first, and take every 2nd element in that collection as not-to-be-split-by-`,`. Each occurrence of `'` would basically switch that behavior.

Comment: You just noticed(before your edit) that `It's Rain'` would break this string because `i's` contains the quoting character. You also notice that this whole approach is very prone to errors. I'm pretty sure that this is a xy-problem.

Comment: And for CsvHelper, use `csv.Configuration.Quote = '\'';` to define quote as singlequote

Comment: Bloody hell, I miss that. And no Parser will accept Multiple char and different delimeter for starts and ends. 
And how `"N'Hello, World , It's Rain', picture"` not parse into `{"Hello, World , It", "s Rain'", " picture"}`? 
Why are those quote in the result? Are delimeter are from `N'` to `',`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following line to split it into an array using more than one char as a separator, given that your string values are separated using a comma followed by space as shown in your example.

`String[] strValues = strValue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Here's a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/idIukJ)

---

Edit - Given the sudden change of requirements...

If you don't care about the order of the results and you want to extract the sentences given that they are all in the same format again `('N<sentence>')` we can use something like this to quickly extract the values:

```
String strValue = "city, image, N'Hello, World , It Rain', picture";

// Match the sentences by N'{text}'
var strValues = Regex.Match(strValue, "(?<=N')(.*?)(?=')");

// Remove the sentences from the string
foreach(var matchedVal in strValues.Captures){
    var toRepl = String.Format("N'{0}', ", matchedVal.ToString());
    strValue = strValue.Replace(toRepl, "");
}

// Split the remainder of the string
List<string> strOtherValues = strValue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

// Add all sentences to words list
foreach (var matchedVal in strValues.Captures)
{
    strOtherValues.Add(matchedVal.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just wrote up a fiddle for this to correct my deleted answer :) Here it is: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l6YVdt

Comment: @JayGould I literally edited it with mine when you posted this comment! Thanks and sorry!

Comment: Ha, no worries. Weird timing all around :)

Comment: Sorry, but string in N'' is a paragraph, ex: N'Hello, World , It's Rain'

Comment: Well, sorry but that wasn't in the question and we are not mind readers.

Comment: @Jun89 - How do you know `N'Hello, World , It's Rain'` "belongs together" and shouldn't just be `N'Hello, World , It'`?

Comment: Thanks @Adriani6 , it's work, I marked your answer is correct. You save my day

Answer (score 0):

Seems your string format is known to have 4 fields comma separated, in this case use regex knowing that the 3rd field could have commas:

```
    String strValue = "city, image, N'Hello, World , It Rain', picture";
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^,]+), ([^,]+), (.+), ([^,]+)");

    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(strValue);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed you need it in c#, my answer is in java but the regex expression should be the same so easily adaptable

Answer (score 0):

Well, *this* is a perfect mess; probably with horrible performance, too. But at least it *seems* to do what you want (haven't tested a lot of corner cases).

The problem is, that you need to somehow distinguish between being "inside" or "outside" an "escaped" part of the original string. If you're "inside", then the normal splitting by separator shoud **not** be done.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> MySpecialSplit(string value, string separator, string escapeStart, string escapeEnd)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var start = value.StartsWith(separator) ? separator.Length : 0;
    var inEscape = false;

    for (var i = start; i < value.Length - separator.Length; i++)
    {
        if (inEscape && value.Length > i + escapeEnd.Length && value.Substring(i, escapeEnd.Length).Equals(escapeEnd))
        {
            inEscape = false;
        }
        else if (!inEscape && value.Length > i + escapeStart.Length && value.Substring(i, escapeStart.Length).Equals(escapeStart))
        {
            inEscape = true;
        }

        if (!inEscape && value.Substring(i, separator.Length).Equals(separator))
        {
            result.Add(value.Substring(start, i - start));
            i += separator.Length;
            start = i;
            i--;
        }
    }

    if (start < value.Length - separator.Length)
    {
        var rest = value.Substring(start);
        if (rest.EndsWith(separator))
        {
            rest = rest.Substring(0, rest.Length - separator.Length);
        }
        result.Add(rest);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use it like:

```
var splitted = MySpecialSplit("city, image, N'Hello, World , It's Rain', picture", ", ", "N'", "',");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, splitted));
```

Result:

```
city
image
N'Hello, World , It's Rain'
picture
```